# Modeling with ordinal dependent variable

Tags: ordinal-data

My dependent variable is of type ordinal. To model it I used ordinal logistic regression and random forest. I wonder what other models I can apply in this case? are classifications models(KNN, SVM, Naive Bayes..) appropriate to use without losing the order, I mean do they consider the variable as ordinal or nominal?

Comment: Just to have this mentioned, although ordinal log. regression and random forest maybe better: You could in principle also apply methods for nominal or interval scaled data. The former don't use some information that you have, the latter "make up" some information that you don't have, however if you have an appropriate loss function for your application, you can actually see how much damage this does and whether it in fact performs decently, which is possible.

Comment: The real issue when applying general machine learning methods is how to choose a suitable loss function for ordinal data. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338904/measures-of-ordinal-classification-error-for-ordinal-regression

Comment: This one doesn't look bad: https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-trick-to-train-an-ordinal-regression-with-any-classifier-6911183d2a3c

Comment: I want to treat loss similarly without weighting. So the loss function gonna be the same. Can u explain further this sentencer plz "The former don't use some information that you have, the latter "make up" some information that you don't have".

Comment: and so which to choose in ur opinion? I am getting confused? Is there a problem with ordinal regression that i ram not seing?

Comment: First comment: If you treat ordinal data as nominal, you lose the information about the order. If you treat ordinal data as interval, you pretend that the order information is stronger (namely numerical, regarding differences) than it actually is. However, if your loss function appropriately formalises what's really relevant in the application, a method that works well regarding that loss is good, regardless of the information treatment issues.

Comment: Second comment: You can try out all kinds of methods, do cross-validation or the like, and choose what produces the lowest loss. This may or may not be ordinal regression. Nothing wrong with ordinal regression, you just may find out that regarding your specific loss you do better using something else.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the encoding of your data. Ordinal data implies some ranking, e.g. like school grades or reviews on amazon.

If you use a very simple encoding scheme (0 < 1 < 2 ... < N) then the order will be considered. However you imply distances, which not always represent reality.

**Example**: 'small', 'medium' and 'large' have an ordering, if you encode it with 0:'small', 1:'medium', 2:'large' you tell your model a large object is always 2 times larger than a medium sized object, which is probably not true for all cases.

Comment: it is simply ordered classes: between 10%-20%; between 20%-30%; between 50%-100% ( those are my classes). i applied ordinal logistic regression and it gives me a great accuracy, random forest as well. But i am wondering what else i can use to model

Comment: Decision Trees and Gradient Boosting are models that can handle ordinal / nominal features quite well.